So does Passport req.login() persist User in Session?
Though I've been working with node express for over two years now, passport/saml authentication is brand new to me. I've noticed that documentation about this is very thin, incomplete and sometimes conflicting, and I cannot find an "official", "real world", example. Furthermore, any example I find does not work out of the box; I've had to tweak them to make them work.
However, I have been successfull in implementing a proof of concept, using WordPress as an IDP.
What I am not clear at is req.isAuthenticated(). Once I am logged in, for subsequent authorization, my strategy skips the IDP, and passport.deserializeUser() is called instead. This simply retrieves the last user saved into the session (and if that is not null, then I am considered authenticated). The problem with this is that when I log out of WordPress, my website still thinks I'm logged in until the session ends.
Is this the intended behaviour? I notice that if I omit calling req.logIn() in my ACS, then the whole passport serializeUser() and deserializeUser() are skipped. That's good because then the IDP is always requested. So then I have to make a custom "isAuthenticated" check. That's fine, but I have hacked this thing to heck, and I really want to use out-of-the-box solutions.
Could somebody, please, show me if I'm missing something? BTW, this is how I am consuming the SAML in my ACS:
import * as express from 'express';
import { ApiRoot } from '..';
import { passport } from '../Services/Saml';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

class AuthorizationController {
    private _Path = '/Authorization';
    private router = express.Router();

    /**
     * Create a new instance of our AuthorizationController object.
     */
    constructor()
    {
        // Set the routes and end points. We only need one for now, the one that consumes the SAML.
        this.router.post(
            `${ApiRoot}${this._Path}/SAML/Consume`,
            bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }),
            this.ConsumeSaml
        );
    }

    /****************************************************************************************/

    /**
     * Consume the SAML returned by the IDP.
     */
    private ConsumeSaml = (req: any,
                           res: express.Response,
                           next: any) => 
    {
        passport.authenticate(
            "saml", 
            {
                session: false 
            },
            (_err, user: any) =>
            {
                // We need to call req.logIn() (because this is apparently a custom ACS) so that 
                // passport serializeUser() and deserializeUser() gets called.
                req.logIn(user, (err: any) =>
                {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        return (next(err));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.redirect(req.body.RelayState);
                    }
                });
            }
        )(req, res, next);
    }
}

export default AuthorizationController;

This is my strategy, serializeUser() and deserializeUser(), etc.:
import passport from "passport";
import SysTrick from "../Helpers/SysTrick";
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

// Setup the SAML configuration.
const _SamlConfig = {
    entryPoint: "entrypoint",
    callbackUrl: `callback`,
    issuer: "issuer",
    cert: "cert",
};

// Setup the SAML stragety.
const _Strategy = new SamlStrategy(
    _SamlConfig,
    (profile, done) => {
        console.log("strategy");
        
        return (done(null, { "id": profile.nameID }));
    }
);

// Setup passport.
passport.use('saml', _Strategy);

passport.serializeUser((user: any, done) => {
    console.log(`serializeUser| id = ${user.id}`);

    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log(`deserializeUser| id = ${id}`);

    return (done(null, (id ? { "id" : id } : null)));
});

export { passport };

This is how I initialize my server:
    this._App.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    this._App.use(bodyParser.json())

    // Session configuration.       
    const sessionConfig: any = {
        secret: "secret",
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { 
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2 
        },
        resave: false,
        store: new this._FileStore({
            path: './sessions/',
        }),
    }
    if (SysTrick.IsProduction) 
    {
        this._App.set('trust proxy', 1);        //.. trust first proxy
        sessionConfig.cookie.secure = true;     //.. serve secure cookies (can only be used with https clients)
    }

    // Enable cors if we are in development.
    if (!SysTrick.IsProduction)
    {
        this._App.use(cors());
    }

    // Limit the size of the inload that will be processed.
    this._App.use(express.json({ limit: '15mb' }));

    // Add security.
    this._App.use(helmet({
        contentSecurityPolicy: false,           //.. easiest way to allow external scripts (e.g., for awsomefonts) to run
        frameguard: false                       //.. allow views to show in iframes
    }));

    // Have Node serve our React application (views).
    this._App.use(express.static(App.ViewsPath));

    // Setup the Express global error handler.
    this._App.use(
        function(error: any, _req: express.Request, res, next)
        {
            // Log the error.
            try   { Log.Error(error, "Global Error Handler"); }
            catch { /* */ }

            // Display the error on the console.
            console.log(chalk.red.bold("ERROR"));
            console.log(chalk.red.bold("====="));
            console.log(error);

            // Because we hook post-response processing into the global error handler, we get
            // to leverage unified logging and error handling; but, it means the response may
            // have already been committed, since we don't know if the error was thrown PRE or
            // POST response. As such, we have to check to see if the response has been
            // committed before we attempt to send anything to the user.
            if (!res.headersSent)
            {
                res.status(500).send("Internal server error.");
            }
        }
    );

    // Add the session storage.
    this._App.use(session(sessionConfig));

    // Add passport for SAML SSO.
    this._App.use(passport.initialize());
    this._App.use(passport.session());

And this is my test route using the test authentication:
    // Test public route.
    this._App.get(
        "/public",
        CheckAuthorization,
        (req, res, next) => 
        {
            res.send("I have been authorised!");
        }
    );

    // This route is for passport-SAML authorization via WordPress.
    this._App.get(
        App.LoginUrl,
        (req: any, res, next) => 
        {
            // We set the req.query.RelayState, after using session in the Check-Auth()
            // middlware. The reason why we have to use req.query.RelayState and not session
            // all the way to the ACS is because the session value is undefined for some reaon
            // in the ACS.
            req.query.RelayState = req.session.OriginalUrl;

            passport.authenticate('saml')(req, res, next);
        }
    );

    // This middleware is for protecting routes with with passport-SAML authorization.
    function CheckAuthorization(req: any, res: any, next: any)
    {
        // The IDP is bypassed, constantly calling passport.deserializeUser(), which has a valid user
        // if the session hasn't ended. Will have to override this checker.
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
        {
            next();
        } 
        else
        {
            // NOTE: We use session here because saving to req.query.RelayState does not
            // work from this middleware. It is in the actual route that calls 
            // passport.authenticate() that req.query.RelayState works. This is all an ugly
            // hack. This whole SAML business is a hack, and proper documentation/example is
            // non-existent.
            req.session.OriginalUrl = req.originalUrl;

            // Redirect to the login route, which is really a call to the IDP.
            res.redirect(App.LoginUrl);
        }
    }



... The problem with this is that when I log out of WordPress, my website still thinks I'm logged in until the session ends.
Is this the intended behaviour? ...

You click logout at wordpress and expect it to propagate logout to your SP(?) i.e. you are talking about IdP initiated SLO (single logout).
I am not familiar with using Wordpess as SAML IdP but maybe you are using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-wp-as-saml-idp/
At the time of writing aforementioned page says that SLO is premium feature:


Single Logout
Terminate user’s Single Sign-On session on WordPress as well as on Service Provider applications, when the user logs out of your WP site or any configured Service Provider application. (Premium Feature)


So you would have to have that enabled in order to have chance to accomplish IdP initiated SLO.
Furthermore SLO is harder than SSO. passport-saml doesn't provide fully functional SLO out of the box. See further details from: https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/blob/v5.0.0/README.md#slo-single-logout
tl;dr; there are multiple things that you have to consider when implementing support for IdP initiated SLO and implementation depends on how you have choosef to manage sessions etc.
And last but not least answer to your question: if your IdP doesn't support SLO (or if you have not implemented support for SLO to your application) it is expected behaviour
